# How to know if a Node x has every instance of node z where it has many relationship to another node y that has one relationship to another node z?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have a node `:Customer` that has many node `:Order`, and `:Order` has to 1 relationship to node `:Shipper` called `:SHIP_VIA` here is the hierarchy:

```
(customer:Customer)-[:PURCHASED]->(order)-[:SHIP_VIA]->(shipper:Shipper)
```

now there are only 3 shippers, and Orders point at them, and a customer would have many orders. So my question is **how to get all customers that has shipped with all shippers?** Note that every shipper has a `shipperID` Attribute inside it. here is my code but its not working except with one "where exists"

```
match (customer:Customer)-[:PURCHASED]->(order)-[:SHIP_VIA]->(shipper:Shipper) 

WHERE exists((customer)-[:PURCHASED]->(order)-[:SHIP_VIA]->(:Shipper 

{shipperID:1})) and exists((customer)-[:PURCHASED]->(order)-[:SHIP_VIA]->

(:Shipper {shipperID:2})) and exists((customer)-[:PURCHASED]->(order)-

[:SHIP_VIA]->(:Shipper {shipperID:3})) return  customer, order , shipper;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution using [collect()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) and [all()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all) functions:

```
// match all shippers
match (shipper:Shipper)
// create a list containing all shippers and pass to the next context
with collect(shipper) as shippers

// match all customers which has purchased an order with each shipper
match (customer:Customer)
where all (shipper in shippers where (customer)-[:PURCHASED]->(:Order)-[:SHIP_VIA]->(shipper))

// return customers
return customer
```

Comment: Thank you that completely worked , and thank you for the comments to understand .

Comment: Hi @OmarBassyouni you are welcome! Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @OmarBassyouni please make sure to accept the answer (green tick it) if it resolved your problem. FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication for the viewers that this answer is the appropriate solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the total number of shippers
2. For each customer, verify that the number of unique shippers is equal to the total number of shippers

---

```
MATCH (shipper:Shipper) 
WITH count(shipper) AS totalShippers

MATCH (customer:Customer)-[:PURCHASED]->(order)-[:SHIP_VIA]->(shipper:Shipper)
WITH totalShippers, customer, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT shipper) as shippers WHERE totalShippers = shippers

RETURN customer
```

Comment: This  Code worked , Thank you . but if you add some comments to understand it would be really great . Thank you